# MAC Slave - SSH connection is failing

Tags: macos, ssh, putty

I am administrator in my new MAC m/c.  (OS X 10.9.2)
I am trying to connect to the MAC via putty from a Windows m/c

I have ensured that I have given correct IP, port, user credentials.

Also /etc/sshd_config - is set as given below
PasswordAuthentication yes

But still I am getting 
"Access Denied
keyboard-interactive authentication failed"

How to resolve this?

(I am not very familiar with MAC. Just bought recently and learning. So, Please try to give some detailed answers if possible. Thank You)

Comment: Why would you ask this question on a site that focuses on software development and programming?

Comment: Sorry! that was by mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up System Preferences and click on the "Sharing" icon.
Make sure that you have "Remote Login" checked, it's off by default.